# Is those who are practising spiritual they have to sleep after lunch or not?

Tags: food, spirituality

I have watched some lecture of Rajiv Dixit on youtube. He was saying  that after  lunch you must have at least a short nap/sleep for 1 hrs.

Once  I read in Swami Sivananda books  that  He was saying that don't sleep in day time and don't waste  even  a single minutes.

These two statement by Swami Sivananda and Rajiv dixt  are opposite to each other

So here I'm confusing that those  who are practicing spiritual  they  have to sleep  after lunch or not ?

I need a right/proper guidance.

Comment: A yogi should always be awake even in sleep. :)

Comment: im not getting can u elaborate more @TheLittleNaruto

Comment: @jasmine, if you are a student (brahmachari), then no sleeping during daytime. if you are a householder, short nap is allowed. if you are a spiritual aspirant, then again, no sleeping during daytime because it interferes with meditation/yoga. if you are a really serious & advanced spiritual aspirant, short nap is allowed, because you'll realize that lack of sleep also interferes with meditation/yoga. once you become an actual spiritual person, you won't have this question any longer because sleep or no sleep doesn't affect you.

Comment: thanks u for ur right guidance  @ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends upon what kind of spiritual practice you are doing. Unless you are doing some high level yogic practices you can take a short nap after lunch, but no need to go into deep slumber.

The reason for taking a nap is that after eating the *jatharagni* in the body can come into play and help digest the food better if you are not engaged in other other activities. Swami Sivananda has said not to waste even a minute to remind the practitioners to be alert and cautious about not wasting time in useless sleeping. It doesn't mean you should not take a short nap or give your body the right amount of sleep it needs. Even yogis of highest level also sleep, however their sleep is different than ours. They are awake even while asleep, but no need to emulate that.

Answer (score 1):

A Yogi should always be awake even in deep sleep. This is covered in [Spandakarika, Section I, verse 20-21](https://www.amazon.in/Spanda-Karikas-Creative-Pulsation-Karikas-Spanda-Nirnaya/dp/8120808215). Verse 20 says what problems awakened one will face.

> Aprabudhadhiyas tvete svasthitisthaganodyatäh/
>
> Pitayanti duruttire ghore samsira-vartmani//20
>
> These (the gunas etc), however, intent on veiling their real nature push the people of unawakened intellect into the terrible ocean of transmigratory existence from which it is difficult to pull them out.

In verse 21, author says

> Atha satatam udyukta spanda-tattva-viviktaye/
>
> Jigrndeva nijam bhavam acirenādhigacchati//21
>
> **Therefore, one should be always on the alert for the discernment of the Spanda principle.** Such a person attains his essential state (as Spanda) even in the waking condition in short time.

---

<sup>***Please note Spanda principle is dynamic creative pulsation or dynamic aspect of divine.**</sup>

Comment: you're giving phd level answer to a 10th class question ??

Comment: @ram What is PhD level in that? Please let me know I'll add more content to make it simpler. Would be great if you point out in the answer specifically. Anyway there are only two verses I have added.

Comment: OP is simply asking whether it's ok to sleep in afternoon or not. Your answer is about how one should NEVER be asleep, which is possible only for yogeshwars